# "You have successfully registered and logged in." vs "You have been successfully registered and logged in."

Tags: word-choice, tenses

After the user press the submit button and everything in the registration form is correct he is automatically registered and logged in. And the message is shown in a pop up window. However, I am not sure which form is better to use. Please, explain which sentence is better and why. Thanks.

> You have successfully registered and logged in.

or

> You have been successfully registered and logged in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion the first is better because it is considered better to use the active voice. :-) The most common reasons I've heard follow.

1. Word economy
2. More gripping sentences

Comment: If 'it is considered better to use the active voice', I'd have expected you to use it.

Comment: @Barrie, surely the smiley gave the topical humor away.

Comment: Oh yeh. Didn't notice. Sorry. But in any case there is no reason in principle to prefer one over the other.

Comment: It is grammar-by-edict for sure. To me, it does have a stylistic use. One can deliberately adhere to it or break it for effect, or, at least, variety.